# Como zerar ou reinicializar as variaveis do app?

Tags: android, android-studio

Estou começando em desenvolvimento Android(usando linguagem JAVA).Estou desenvolvendo um app de calculo de média que exibe a média e a situação do aluno(Aprovado,Em recuperação e Reprovado).
A minha pergunta é como zerar ou reinicializar as variaveis do app.

Obs: Inserir algumas condições como:Não receber valores abaixo de 0 ou acima de 10.E não receber valores nulos ou com espaços.

Exemplo de execução:

1º Execução:

Nota 1:9
Nota 2:6 
Média: 7

2º Execução:

Nota 1:8
Nota 2:11
Média: 7 (Continua o mesmo valor da execução anterior)

Como posso reverter isso?Existe algum comando especifico que pode ser inserido no fim do app para reinicializar os valores?

Código do app (Manifest):

```
package com.example.notasescolares;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    //Declarando objetos JAVA
    EditText edtNota1,edtNota2;
    TextView txtMedia,txtSituacao;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //Interligando o XML ao JAVA
        edtNota1 = findViewById(R.id.edtNota1);
        edtNota2 = findViewById(R.id.edtNota2);
        txtMedia = findViewById(R.id.txtMedia);
        txtSituacao = findViewById(R.id.txtSituacao);
    }

    //Quando clicado o botão acontece um evento
    public void processar(View view) {
        boolean ok = true;

        //Lógica para não crashar o app
        if(edtNota1.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()){
            ok = false;
            edtNota1.setError(getText(R.string.msgErroNumVazio));
        }

        if(edtNota2.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()){
            ok = false;
            edtNota2.setError(getText(R.string.msgErro));
        }

        if(ok == true) {
            float nota1 = Float.parseFloat(edtNota1.getText().toString());
            float nota2 = Float.parseFloat(edtNota2.getText().toString());
            float media;
            boolean numValido = true;

            //Verificando numeros validos recebidos(0 a 10)
            if(nota1 < 0 || nota1 > 10){
                edtNota1.setError(getText(R.string.msgErro));
                numValido = false;
            }
            if(nota2 < 0 || nota2 > 10){
                edtNota2.setError(getText(R.string.msgErro));
                numValido = false;
            }

            //Se valido execute o processamento
            if(numValido) {
                //Calculo da média
                 media = (nota1 + nota2) / 2;

                //Definindo situação
                txtMedia.setText(String.format("%.2f", media));
                if(media >= 7) {            //Aprovado
                    txtSituacao.setText(R.string.strAprovado);
                }else if (media >= 5) {     //Recuperação
                    txtSituacao.setText(R.string.strRecuperacao);
                }else {                     //Reprovado
                    txtSituacao.setText(R.string.strReprovado);
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//Quando clicado o botão acontece um evento
    public void processar(View view) {
        boolean ok = true;
        float nota1 = 0;
        float nota2 = 0;
        float media = 0;
        boolean numValido = false;

        //Lógica para não crashar o app
        if(edtNota1.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()){
            ok = false;
            edtNota1.setError(getText(R.string.msgErroNumVazio));
        }

        if(edtNota2.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()){
            ok = false;
            edtNota2.setError(getText(R.string.msgErro));
        }

        if(ok == true) {
            nota1 = Float.parseFloat(edtNota1.getText().toString());
            nota2 = Float.parseFloat(edtNota2.getText().toString());
            media;
            numValido = true;

            //Verificando numeros validos recebidos(0 a 10)
            if(nota1 < 0 || nota1 > 10){
                edtNota1.setError(getText(R.string.msgErro));
                numValido = false;
            }
            if(nota2 < 0 || nota2 > 10){
                edtNota2.setError(getText(R.string.msgErro));
                numValido = false;
            }

            //Se valido execute o processamento
            if(numValido) {
                //Calculo da média
                 media = (nota1 + nota2) / 2;

                //Definindo situação
                txtMedia.setText(String.format("%.2f", media));
                if(media >= 7) {            //Aprovado
                    txtSituacao.setText(R.string.strAprovado);
                }else if (media >= 5) {     //Recuperação
                    txtSituacao.setText(R.string.strRecuperacao);
                }else {                     //Reprovado
                    txtSituacao.setText(R.string.strReprovado);
                }
                nota1 = 0;
                nota2 = 0;
                media = 0;
                numValido = false;
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Eu acrescentei essas linhas de código que você sugeriu.Mas diz que a variavel não aceita null(float e null incompatible types).E em vez de null tentei inserir zero nas variaveis.Mas mesmo assim ficou a mesma coisa.Está exibindo os resultados da 1º execução (dados corretos) e a 2ªexecuçãos(dados errados) não calculando mas exibindo os valores da 1ª.

Comment: atualizei a resposta, talvez colocando a  declaração das variáveis ao entrar nesse método não dê esse problema

Answer (score 0):

Você aparentemente não precisa recuperar a view no seu processa. Chamar essa função dentro do seu setOnClickListener do botão.

```
private boolean processa(){
//testo se é float ou não
try {
     Float.parseFloat(string)

 float nota1 = Float.parseFloat(edtNota1.getText().toString());
        float nota2 = Float.parseFloat(edtNota2.getText().toString());
        float media;
        boolean numValido = true;

            //Verificando numeros validos recebidos(0 a 10)
            if(nota1 < 0 || nota1 > 10 || (nota2 < 0 || nota2 > 10){
// retorna mensagem ao usuario de erro
                return false;
            }
            //Calculo da média
             media = (nota1 + nota2) / 2.0; // para retornar as frações

            //Definindo situação
            txtMedia.setText(String.valueOf(media));
            if(media >= 7) {            //Aprovado
                txtSituacao.setText(R.string.strAprovado);
               return true;
            }else if (media >= 5) {     //Recuperação
                txtSituacao.setText(R.string.strRecuperacao);
               return true;
            }else {                     //Reprovado
                txtSituacao.setText(R.string.strReprovado);
               return true;
            }

}
catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
//retorno mensagem pedindo pra inserir um numero
}
}
```